# Фильтрация массива по заданным условиям

Tags: java, массивы, методы, filter

Задача в том чтобы вернуть массив целых чисел, делящихся на divider без остатка и эти числа должны быть положительные.
Например:

```java
int[] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
int divider = 2;
```

То результат:

```java
int[] result = {2, 8};
```

Мой код:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
        int divider = 2;
        int[] res = getDivisibleNumbers(numbers, divider);

        for (int arr : res) {
            System.out.print(arr + " ");
        }
    }

    public static int[] getDivisibleNumbers(int[] numbers, int divider) {
        int[] test = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % divider == 0 && numbers[i] > 0) {
                test[i] = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return test;
    }
}
```

Вывод получается:

```
2 0 8 0 0 0 0
```

Подскажите как правильно решить. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае у вас есть несколько возможных решений. Самое оптимальное решение в данном случае - использовать стрим:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
        int divider = 2;
        int[] res = getDivisibleNumbers(numbers, divider);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    }

    public static int[] getDivisibleNumbers(int[] numbers, int divider) {
        return Arrays.stream(numbers)
                .filter(numb -> numb % divider == 0 && numb > 0)
                .toArray();
    }
    
}
```

Это решает главную проблему - создание результирующего массива. Ведь в момент его создания вам неизвестна его длина (отсюда и 0 в вашем решении). Посему лучше брать стрим, тогда о размере массива заботиться не придется.

Как вариант , вы можете использовать коллекцию ArrayList, инкапсулирующую массив для того, чтобы добавлять в нее необходимые числа. А уже после наполнения вызывать метод toArray(), преобразуя ее в массив. И,разумеется, можно сделать 2 прохода по циклу. Первый проход подсчитает кол-во нужных вам цифр, что позволит создать массив нужного размера. Второй проход добавит все цифры в уже созданный массив. Нерационально. но возможно.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Как раз, нерациональный подход(с помощью циклов) это то, что требуется для решания этой задачи, так как до коллекций и Stream еще не дошел.

Answer (score 0):

Для обхода элементов массива `int[]` можно использовать метод [`Arrays.stream(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) и далее применить цепочку фильтров:

```java
int[] numbers = {2, 5, 8, 0, 7, 1, -4};
int divider = 2;

int[] res = Arrays.stream(numbers)
        // делятся без остатка на 'divider'
        .filter(i -> i % divider == 0)
        // положительные
        .filter(i -> i > 0)
        // собираем в массив
        .toArray();

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res)); // [2, 8]
```